# Lambdify not working in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, sympy, lambdify

I've recently tried running the lambdify function, based on SymPy, on Google Colab, but am not having any success. The same code works on Spyder and Jupyter Notebook, but still no luck.

Link to code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sBJm3pKfOKrl6oIqYV27RIr7fNWRzktI?usp=sharing

Any suggestions?

Comment: The default version of SymPy in Google Colab is 1.1.1. Later versions of SymPy should work. To upgrade, type `!pip install sympy --upgrade` and restart the runtime.